# PHP Array into HTML table for email

Tags: php, html, email

I try to put data from a PHP array into a HTML Table and make an email with it. I can't seem to get the array to combine with the HTML.

I want to make a two column wide table with the  fields array details below them.
I've tried to use a forearch but without succes.

```
 $subject = 'Nieuwe reservering';

$fields = array('kosten' => 'kosten' , 'name' => 'Naam', 'surname' => 'Achternaam', 'phone' => 'Telefoonnummer', 'kamer' => 'Kamer', 'aankomst' => 'aankomst', 'vertrek' => 'vertrek', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Bericht');

$okMessage = 'Je bericht is verstuurd, dankjewel!';

$errorMessage = 'Oei er ging iets fout, geeft niks. Probeer het later opnieuw.';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{
    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .="<table>";
            $emailText .= "<td>" "$fields[$key]: $value\n" "</td>";
            $emailText .="</table>";
        }
    }

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers = array('Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
```

Comment: voting as a typo. Missing a dot for the last header declaration.

Comment: Also, `$emailText .= "td"` should be `<td>`

Comment: and `\n` is not valid HTML. `<br>` is a line break. However, you should not be using linebreaks in `<table>`'s

Comment: This is a syntax error: `$emailText .= "<td>" "$fields[$key]: $value\n" "</td>";`  Surely your PHP logs are telling you exactly that.  Unless some other error stopped execution before it got to that line.  Either way, check your PHP logs.

Comment: @David Right and they're probably going to be editing on the fly again, as they did in regards to the 2nd comment by Kolob.

Comment: I noticed the missing <td> before i read the comment. However i missed the /n :)

Comment: `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";` never happened.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change this :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .="<table>";
            $emailText .= "td" "$fields[$key]: $value\n" "</td>";
            $emailText .="</table>";
        }
    }
```

To :

```
$emailText ="<table>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "<tr><td>{$fields[$key]}: $value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
$emailText .="</table>";
```

Or if you want all of them in the same `<tr>` :

```
$emailText ="<table><tr>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     if (isset($fields[$key])) {
          $emailText .= "<td>{$fields[$key]}: $value</td>";
        }
     }
$emailText .="</tr></table>";
```

Comment: It did work actually, however every element from the row is placed in a seperate <tr> I'm now trying to figure out how to make a label for it and give it borders with CSS.

Comment: edited with an example if you want all fields in the same `<tr>`